# Why does typescript not flag that my function which technically returns "any" might not return the desired interface?

Tags: typescript

```
function test(p: any): { method: () => string } {
    return p;
}

test(1).method()
```

this will cause an error, but typescript will not flag it. why is it so and how can i avoid such unexpected errors?

Comment: This is how `any` works (don’t use `any`). Maybe you’re thinking of `unknown`, or `test<T>(p: T)`?

Comment: @Ry- the problem was that the param passed to the callback for `.catch` called on a `Promise` has type `any`,  which is not something I can control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what the [`any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) actually does.

> TypeScript also has a special type, any, that you can use whenever you
> don’t want a particular value to cause typechecking errors.
>
> When a value is of type any, you can access any properties of it
> (which will in turn be of type any), call it like a function, assign
> it to (or from) a value of any type, or pretty much anything else
> that’s syntactically legal.

<sub>https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any</sub>

A variable of type `any` can be assigned literally any type. Essentially, you turn off type checking.

```
let any: any;
any = "";
any = 3;
any = true;
any = () => void 0;
...
```

Furthermore, a variable of type `any` can also be assigned to any other variable (even if it has an explicit type annotation).

```
let any: any;

const string: string = any;
const number: number = any;
const obj: { method: () => string } = any;
...
// There's just one edge case with the never type.
const never: never = any;
//    ~~~~~ Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

To fully unterstand what's going on, we need to take a deeper look at how type compatibility works in TypeScript. We distinguish two types of compatibility: *Subtype* and *Assignment*. The only difference is that *Assignment* augments the *Subtype* compatibility with certain rules. One of these rules is to allow assignment to and from `any`.

See [Subtype vs Assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#subtype-vs-assignment) and [Any Do's and Don'ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any)

Comment: thanks, i didn't know what to search up on my own. that being said, what's the solution to avoiding unexpected errors where `any` is involved? just avoid it entirely? what about for cases like the callback passed to `.catch()` accepting a parameter of type `any`? (`.catch( (e: any) => {} )`)?

Comment: You might want to link to [this doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any) as well

Comment: @jcalz if we shouldn't use any, why does the param passed to the callback for `.catch` called on a `Promise` have type `any`?